# Cannot scrape the correct aspect ration of the image - Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm having a problem to extract an image from a "Manga" website using python.
Below is the element example on the website:

- img id="comic" class="loading" onerror="this.src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'; this.removeAttribute('onerror'); this.className = 'loaderror';" src="https://example_on_the_image.jpg"> == $0"

I'm able to parse out the "src" link & the image aspect ratio supposed to be as follow if using normal browser to view:

- Rendered size:    920 × 1301 px
- Rendered aspect ratio:    920∶1301
- Intrinsic size:   720 × 1018 px
- Intrinsic aspect ratio:   360∶509
- File size:    101 kB
- Current source:   (url of the image)

Yet, the image that I have downloaded become "160 x 160px" & file size is lesser.
I have tried using Beautifulsoup, Selenium etc, still getting the same result.

But if I using:

- the browser & right click to "Save Image As"
- Inspect -> on the image element -> right click -> Capture node screenshot

I was able to save "Rendered size" as the above 2 method using normal browsers.
Why using python to scrape, I cannot get the correct aspect ratio??

Hope that somebody can guide me on this or where I did wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'''
Here's my Playwright code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

    manga_url = ("the url that u going to scrape")
    dwn_path = your_directory
    os.chdir(dwn_path) 

    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=500)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(manga_url)
        page.locator("#comic").screenshot(path="screenshot.png")
        print(page.title())
        browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, Selenium cannot "screenshot" the element in full render size but using Playwright can let me screenshot on the correct aspect ratio that display after browser loaded.